# Concatenate all values of a database table column with comma or "AND"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following requirement for a SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) report: display all the values from a column in a database table in one string, concatenated as follows:

1. if there is just one value, display it
2. if there are two values, concatenate them with a comma (",")
3. if there are more than two values, concatenate all except the last two with a comma (",") and the last two with ", AND"
4. values should be distinct, i.e. no two repeating values are allowed

To illustrate, if the values of the column in question, let's call it Column1, are:

> ### Column1
>
> Apple
>
> Potato
>
> Potato
>
> Pear
>
> Grapes

The resulting string should be:

> Apple, Potato, Pear, and Grapes

So my question is, how can i do that in a SQL statement? I can accomplish #1, #2, and #4 with the following SQL, but #3 escapes me:

```
SELECT Stuff(
  (SELECT DISTINCT
        N', ' + Table1.Column1
   FROM
        Table2
                INNER JOIN Table ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table2ID_FK
   WHERE
    dbo.Table2.SomeId = 100
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'');
```

Comment: I think you mean `Pear and Grapes` instead of `Pear, and Grapes`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - Actually that comma is perfectly valid and in some cases can actually lead to a clearer understanding. It is known as a serial comma. Here is a great discussion the topic. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It's called a [Serial Comma or Oxford Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). In her style guide Eats, Shoots & Leaves, Lynne Truss writes: "There are people who embrace the Oxford comma, and people who don't, and I'll just say this: never get between these people when drink has been taken."

Comment: @SqlZim LOL. No kidding. Some people get really adamant about which one is "correct". :D

Comment: No, I meant "Pear, Grapes". I believe that is the correct grammar.

Comment: "Pear, and Grapes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Len(intr) - Len(Replace(intr, ',', '')) > 1 THEN Stuff(intr, ( Len(intr) - Charindex(',', Reverse(intr)) ) + 2, 0, ' and ')
         ELSE intr
       END
FROM   (SELECT Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + Table1.Column1
                      FROM   Table2
                             INNER JOIN Table
                                     ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table2ID_FK
                      WHERE  dbo.Table2.SomeId = 100
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) .value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'') AS intr)a
```

Comment: That almost works, but it does put ", and" even if there are only two values for the column.

Comment: @lukegf - check now

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`with (common table expression)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) we can reference target result set easily with subqueries to find the last value and the count of values in the list.

Using a `case` expression to add `'and '` when `col =` the last value and a subquery to check the `count(*)` of the values being returned:

rextester: http://rextester.com/QDTJ44637

```
with t as (
  select col 
  from (values ('Apple'),('Potato'),('Potato'),('Pear'),('Grapes')) t (col)
)

select stuff((
  select 
        N', ' 
      + case when col = (select top 1 col from t order by col desc)
               and (select count(*) from t)>2
             then 'and ' 
             else '' 
             end 
      + col
   from t
   group by col
   order by col for xml path(''),type)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'');
```

To adapt this for the query in the question, replace the query inside the common table expression `with t as ()` with

```
SELECT DISTINCT col = Table1.Column1 
FROM Table2 
  INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table2ID_FK 
WHERE dbo.Table2.SomeId = 100
```

Comment: This solution is not dynamic and I doubt it meets the OP's needs.

Comment: @JohnJoseph I'm not sure why you think it won't meet OP's needs. If you replace example query in the common table expression `t` with OP's query: `SELECT DISTINCT col = Table1.Column1 FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table2ID_FK WHERE dbo.Table2.SomeId = 100` It will work with that result set just fine.

Comment: Ah... you should edit your answer to point that out, perhaps.

Comment: This works well too and it's actually a tiny bit faster than @Prdp's, although more complicated (I measured speed and complexity with SQL Server's Execution Plan and Client Statistics tools). If possible, I'll mark both as answers. UPDATE: it looks like there can be only one answer, so Prdp's it is, as it came first.

Answer (score 1):

Leave your code (which is working fine) alone.  Outside of that code, fix the issue.  Here's how...

Temporarily, I'll use literals for clarity.  Consider that:

```
    SELECT RIGHT('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes' , CHARINDEX (' ,' ,REVERSE('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes'))+1)
```

...yields: ", Grapes"

Good so far?  Just replace that with "and Grapes" by doing the following...

```
    SELECT REPLACE('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes', RIGHT('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes' , CHARINDEX (' ,' ,REVERSE('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes'))+1), REPLACE(RIGHT('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes' , CHARINDEX (' ,' ,REVERSE('Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes'))+1),',',' and'))
```

So, to make that all dynamic, just replace the literal 'Apple, Potato, Pear, Grapes' with the results of your original query (that you should assign to a variable).

The final code looks like:

```
    DECLARE @OrigValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @OrigValue = 
      Stuff(
      (SELECT DISTINCT
            N', ' + Table1.Column1
       FROM
            Table2
                    INNER JOIN Table ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table2ID_FK
       WHERE
        dbo.Table2.SomeId = 100
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
      .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'');

    SELECT REPLACE(@OrigValue, RIGHT(@OrigValue , CHARINDEX (' ,',REVERSE(@OrigValue))+1), REPLACE(RIGHT(@OrigValue, CHARINDEX (' ,',REVERSE(@OrigValue))+1),',',' and'))
```

Comment: That almost works, but doesn't full fill #2 on my list, i.e. if there are only two values, it concatenates them with " and " instead of comma (",").